# mask input text in IBM BPM

Tags: jquery, ajax, ibm-bpm

I need a mask input field for presenting the account number in my coach view. The field can be filled by data coming from services or manually filled. in both cases it should be like :"XX-XXX-XXXXXXXXXX". how can i do that? also i need an auto complete service if an operator inters 7 digits it should take the first 5 ones for the first and second set and put eight 0s back of the last two digits. as an example if operator inters:12-345-69 it should automatically be completed as: 12-345-0000000069 i am working on BPM v8.5.

thanks

PS: I have to take the input value's length. But since it is masked, the length of the input will always be fixed as 17.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with BP3's Brazos UI Toolkit. There is a free version available as well as a paid Enterprise version with an enhanced control set as well as outstanding support. More info can be found here:
http://www.bp-3.com/brazos/brazos-ui-toolkit/.

Register to receive access to the Brazos UI download [here](http://www2.bp-3.com/brazostoolkitrequest).

Answer (score 2):

Brazos is awesome (and I would recommend you check it out) but your question is essentially a standard web-development one (rather than being IBM BPM-specific).

I guess it makes sense to stick with Dojo for your solution if you decide to implement it yourself (e.g. https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/NumberTextBox.html).